# replace if not exists in sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I was using sed to replace a style rule.
I wanted to replace a string only if it is not already being replaced in a style tag of HTML.
I got it working when the tags are in two separate lines

with this input:

```
<span style="transform: rotate(-0.0154533rad)"></span>
<span style="-webkit-transform: rotate(-0.0280076rad);transform: rotate(-0.0280076rad);"></span>
```

and with the below command

```
sed -i.bak '/-webkit-transform: [a-zA-Z0-9\(\)\.\-]*/! s/transform: [a-zA-Z0-9\(\)\.\-]*/-webkit-&;&/g' a.html
```

I got

```
<span style="-webkit-transform: rotate(-0.0154533rad);transform: rotate(-0.0154533rad)"></span>
<span style="-webkit-transform: rotate(-0.0280076rad);transform: rotate(-0.0280076rad);"></span>
```

But When I give the tags in same line the command doesn't changed the file.
Can anybody tell me why?

AS Kenavoz suggested

```
sed 's/style="\(transform: [^"]*"\)/style="-webkit-\1;\1/g' file.html
```

will work for the above given example. But for a more complex example like this what to do?

```
<span style="color: red;transform: rotate(-0.0154533rad)"></span><span style="color: blue;-webkit-transform: rotate(-0.0280076rad);transform: rotate(-0.0280076rad);"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `[^"]*"` pattern to match any character except `"` ending with a `"` (non greedy matching with sed) :

```
sed '/webkit-transform: [^"]*"/! s/transform: [^"]*"/-webkit-&;&/g' file.html
```

But in your case, i suggest you use this code :

```
sed 's/style="\(transform: [^"]*"\)/style="-webkit-\1;\1/g' file.html
```

to match strings where both style syntax are in the same line :

```
<span style="-webkit-transform: rotate(-0.0280076rad);transform: rotate(-0.0280076rad);"></span> <span style="transform: rotate(-0.0154533rad)"></span>
```

**UPDATE :**

This should work with your new code :

```
sed 's/\(-webkit-\)\(transform:[^"]*\)\(transform[^;"]*\)\([;"]\)/\1_\2_\3\4/g; 
     s/\([^_]\)\(transform:[^;"]*\)\([";]\)/\1-webkit-\2;\2\3/g
     s/_transform/transform/g
' file.html
```

The sed command is composed of 3 substitution commands :

1. Every style containing `-webkit` is modified (adding a `_` prefix to `transform`) to preserve it from second substitution
2. Styles attributes without webkit are updated with the browser prefix
3. `_transform` is restored to initial value

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It correctly selects the tag, but not replacing in sed. I updated the question with the actual file

Comment: Did you try the second command of my answer? It works for me.

Comment: Thank you very much! it is working for the given example. but what if there is some more rules in front of that rule?

Comment: Great ! In your question, you wrote "When I give the tags in same file", i guess you meant "When I give the tags in same line" ?

Comment: It helped for the previously given example, but often the style may not start with the word transform. So I added another example. I am trying with that also. could you also help?